# use of clGetProgramInfo after clBuildProgram failure for device list

Tags: build, opencl

I use `clBuildProgram` to build a program for devices list,containing 10 devices
it fails.I checked that the failure happens due to the compilation problem with one device only.I still want to use `clGetProgramInfo` to extract info for the devices for which compilation was OK.
can I do it?(while still performing `clBuildProgram` for entire device list)
thanks

Comment: Did you try it? I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Is it Ligal?the spec. doesn`t say nothing about clGetProgramInfo execution if build failed - is it undefined? - it can work once and after that (or for another platform) not work